# Best way to handle recyclerview item clicks using rx-android

Tags: rx-java, android-recyclerview, rx-android

I've got this scenario on my recyclerview items:

Once i click an item from my recyclerview, i want to show a detailed info of that item to another activity(say DetailsActivity), and at the same time, leverage the new activity transitions of views(API 21) on that recyclerviewitem.

Found some methods by having itemclick listeners on the views on the recyclerAdapter, but im not really sure on the performance issues that can arise from that.

Ofcourse we can pass the data model residing in that recyclerview item to the activity thru intent bundles/parcelables but, i have exactly no idea how to use it with RxJava/RxAndroid. I have used GreenRobot's event bus but since im using RxJava with retrofit, might as well use that.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this before, and should warn you, its not easy as it may sound

**Step 1** Implement your own simple event bus with RX 
 You can go to this site for that - [weddingpartyapp.com](http://nerds.weddingpartyapp.com/tech/2014/12/24/implementing-an-event-bus-with-rxjava-rxbus/) This is a great tutorial by Kaushik Gopal to create a simple but efficient EventBus using RxAndroid. 
 or you can just use my code from [here](https://github.com/NischalBhatewara/Melody/blob/develop/app/src/main/java/m/nischal/melody/Util/RxBus.java) (it is an abandoned project I started an year ago, but has a working EventBus and the answer to your question)

**Step 2** After you have implemented your EventBus, you'll have to create objects for all the gestures you want to pass around the bus(tap, double tap, long press, etc) 
 Take a look at this code and implement all the objects you need [code](https://github.com/NischalBhatewara/Melody/blob/develop/app/src/main/java/m/nischal/melody/Util/BusEvents.java)

**Step 3** Add this code to your implementation of RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener if you have copied my code, should work-

```
public RecyclerItemClickListener(Context c) {
    bus = ... //get instance of bus
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(c, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            bus.putValue(string, childPosition);
            bus.publish(new BusEvents.RecyclerViewItemClick());
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
            bus.publish(new BusEvents.TapEvent());
        }
    });
}
```

else just do the same with whatever methods you created

Hope that helped!

**EDIT**
weddingpartyapp.com is no longer available. Please use [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20160507034458/http://nerds.weddingpartyapp.com/tech/2014/12/24/implementing-an-event-bus-with-rxjava-rxbus) link from the Way Back Machine for the tutorial.

Comment: hi mate! thanks for this solution. quick question: BusEvents.RecyclerViewItemClick() would contain what? your own set of onclick functions??

Comment: also if my understanding is correct, you also utilized the bus as an array map storage of the position being clicked?

Comment: the bus event class is just a wrapperclass(kinda) for all the events that can happen, and each event is just an empty object. you just pass the empty object around with a string on the bus. eg: a click on position 5 would be a entry in the bus as <str, pos> and published with an object of BusEvents.RecyclerViewItemClick. so all that subscribe to BusEvents.RecyclerViewItemClick wil get the <str, pos> pair. hope that helped!

Comment: hi @hello_world, cannot reached weddingpartyapp.com, can you share another tutorial, or code ?

Comment: @Cüneyt The website is archived at [The Wayback Machine here](http://web.archive.org/web/20160507034458/http://nerds.weddingpartyapp.com/tech/2014/12/24/implementing-an-event-bus-with-rxjava-rxbus)

Comment: @Cüneyt Hey, I have also added the links to my project in the steps. You could refer to them, and the link by rOOb85 is working.

Comment: @hello_world Thank you.